# How to enclose custom server control inside UpdatePanel?

Tags: asp.net, updatepanel, custom-server-controls

I want to make a custom server control that inherits from Gridview but is enclosed inside an UpdatePanel. Something like this :

```
 Public Class CustomGridView
        Inherits GridView

 Protected Sub Render()
  Dim wrapper As New UpdatePanel
  MyBase.parent = wrapper
 End Sub

 End Class
```

Comment: This is all you've tried so far?  What else have you tried?

Comment: I can make a custom updatepanel that includes my control bu I don't want to make another control